# Can't link to lboost_program_options

Tags: c++, linker-errors, boost-program-options

I am trying to compile my project with following g++ command:

```
g++ -Wall -o mdaemon mdaemon-Mdaemon.o mdaemon-Rm.o mdaemon-Share.o mdaemon-SuperDaemon.o mdaemon-wmxver.o  -pthread -L/home/sunshyn/wmx_simmode/src/../cots/lib/i686-redhat-linux-gnu ..//common/libcommon.a ..//common/pm/libpm.a ..//common/br/librouter.a ..//common/br/tcp/libipc_tcp.a ..//common/applink/libapplink.a ..//common/ur/libur.a ..//common/pma/libpma.a ..//common/cma/libcma.a -lbz2 -lcurses -ldl -lpthread -lboost_program_options -lboost_thread
```

This results in the error displayed below:

```
mdaemon-Mdaemon.o(.text+0x29b6): In function `main':
: undefined reference to `boost::program_options::options_description::m_default_line_length'
mdaemon-Mdaemon.o(.text+0x29c0): In function `main':
: undefined reference to `boost::program_options::options_description::options_description(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, unsigned int)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [mdaemon] Error 1
```

Please let me know what is the mistake in the command?

Answer (score 0):

The error most likely means that you did not link your application to the program_options library.

Double check your `-L path` (directory, in addition to the default directories, where to look for libraries).

You could also try to include the full path to the library in the list of files, without -l (e.g. `g++ sources.cc ... /usr/lib/libboost_program_options.a`), to link the static library.

Comment: I have tried the suggested way as well, but the error remains the same. Ofcourse, I have included "boost/program_options.hpp"